# Optimize Active Directory Audit script

Tags: powershell, active-directory

As part of my job i'm constantly auditing active directory for given properties of cross domain accounts.

I've constructed a powershell script to output information to a CSV based on properties given to the script. This is fine, the script works beautifully for a small list of people however i'm noticing that the script slows down considerably when i provide a big list of users to audit.

This is the script:

```
    $inputfile = "C:\Powershell\input.txt"
    $users = Get-Content $inputfile

    $audit = Read-Host "Audit Name"
    $csv = ".\output\Audit\$audit.csv"

    $failed = @()

    $serv = @("server1", "server2", "server3")

    if((Test-Path $csv) -eq $true){Remove-Item $csv}

    foreach($domain in $serv)
    {
        $count = $users.Count
        for( $i=0; $i -le $count - 1; $i++ )
        {
            if (($users.Get($i)) -ne "")
            {
                try
                {
                    Write-Host "Checking for $($users.get($i)) on" -NoNewline
                    switch($domain)
                    { # with fancier text for which domain we're searching
                        "server1" {write-host "...Server1" -ForegroundColor Cyan -NoNewline; $domainCsv = "Server1"}
                        "server2" {Write-Host "...Server2" -ForegroundColor White -NoNewline; $domainCsv = "Server2"}
                        "server3" {Write-Host "...Server3" -ForegroundColor Magenta -NoNewline; $domainCsv = "Server3"}
                    }

                    $usr = Get-ADUser -Identity $users.get($i) -Properties $properties -Server $domain | ? { ($_.distinguishedname -notlike '*Suspended*')}
                    if ($usr -ne $null) 
                    {
                        $usr = Get-ADUser -Identity $users.get($i) -Properties $properties -Server $domain | ? { ($_.distinguishedname -notlike '*Deletion*')}
                        if ($usr -ne $null) 
                        {
                            Write-Host "...Found" -ForegroundColor Green

                            $userobj = New-Object PSObject

                            Add-Member -InputObject $userobj -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "User" -Value $($users.Get($i))
                            Add-Member -InputObject $userobj -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Domain" -Value $domainCsv

                            foreach($prop in $properties) {$userobj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $prop -Value "$($usr.$prop)"}

                            $userobj | Export-Csv $csv -Append -NoTypeInformation
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Write-Host "...Pending Delete" -ForegroundColor Red
                            $failed += "$($users.Get($i)),Pending deletion on $domainCsv"
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Write-Host "...Suspended" -ForegroundColor Red
                        $failed += "$($users.Get($i)),Suspended on $domainCsv"
                    }                       
                }
                catch [System.Exception]
                {
                    Write-Host "...Not found" -ForegroundColor Red
                    $failed += "$($users.Get($i)),Could not find on $domainCsv"
                } # </Try
            } # </If user ""
        } # </For users
    } # </For Domains
    Add-Content $csv ""
    Add-Content $csv "Those who failed, (Not found or Suspended or Pending deletion)"
    Add-Content $csv ""
    Add-Content $csv "User,Domain"
    foreach($fail in $failed) {Add-Content $csv $fail}
    Write-Host " "
    Write-Host "    Audit saved to $csv" -ForegroundColor Green
```

What the script does

Gets input file full of users (one name per line) (mostly 20 or so lines but sometimes the input file has been over 200)

```
user1
user2
user3
user4
user5
```

goes through each domain

checks if they're in an OU for suspended accounts

checks if they're in an OU for accounts pending deletion

if not in either OU grabs the information and puts it into a PSObject for insertion into a CSV

after its done it lists the accounts it couldnt find or were in an OU that i dont need to worry about.

As i'm quite new to powershell i have no idea if theres a way i can condense parts of the code to be quicker, i have read a few pages on optimizing powershell but the only change i could see was to change

`for( $i=0; $i -le $users.count - 1; $i++ )`

to

`$count = $users.count`

`for( $i=0; $i -le $count - 1; $i++ )`

My question is: How can i improve my script to loop faster when given more users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand your script spent most of the time in `Get-ADUser`. You call it twice with the same parameters, using $usr you should call it just one time, your script execution time should bedevided by two.

Another thing, I can't find the defenition of `$properties` in your script, reducing this list can also reduce the network payload.

---

Test something like this.

```
$usr = Get-ADUser -Identity $users.get($i) -Properties $properties -Server $domain | ? { ($_.distinguishedname -notlike '*Suspended*')}
if ($usr.distinguishedname -notlike '*Suspended*') 
{
  if ($usr.distinguishedname -notlike '*Deletion*') 
  {
```

Comment: My apologies, thanks for looking at my script, `$Properties` is the paramater that i musnt have copied in but it usually only contains enabled,description,lastlogondate.

I have found that if i do `$usr = Get-ADUser -Identity $users.get($i) -Properties $properties -Server $domain | ? { ($_.distinguishedname -notlike '*Suspended*') -or ($_.distinguishedname -notlike '*Deletion*') }` then it doesnt exclude either OU and simply returns the user information, is this the correct syntax for checking both condition in the `?` pipe?

Comment: I don't think so. I have no computer to test the exact syntax here, but have a look with you debuger ti $usr var, and test something like my edit code.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @JPBlanc, i was able to comment out the second Get-ADUser call and simply use the if statements to check the distinguished name both times. My script now runs through each user noticeably faster and also correctly catches if a user is in a suspended or deletion OU. Thanks once again, really appreciate you taking the time to suggest improvements.